# Python 2.7: urllib2.urlopen(request) not working with Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, urllib2

I can't make a request with urllib2 if I use Django, however, running the script alone works.

if I run the script alone with the same virtual environment as Django, it works.

the code I am using:

```
data = urllib.urlencode({'somedata':somedata})
url = "https://www.example.com"
request = urllib2.Request(url,data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
print response
```

The problem appears when Django tries to run it, I tried switching networks and OS:

in Ubuntu, I get this error:

`<urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>`

in Windows:

`<urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>`

any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the environment have dns server, and network connection is reachable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```